# NodeJS returns 0 where an integer is expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason my Node JS code always returns 0. The 'price' property is retrieved correctly, but for some reason my method doesn't update the productPrice variable.

Firebase console suggests the following:

```
Error: Invalid integer:
```

However, when I try to log the childData.price value, console reports it correctly, but doesn't add the value to the productPrice variable.

Here's my code:

```
return admin.database().ref('/productAds').orderByChild('code').equalTo(items['code']).once('value').then((snapshot) => {

    var productPrice = 0;
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          productPrice = childData.price;
    });

    return productPrice;
});
```

I tried updating it to += as suggested by @Doug. Realised I was looking into the wrong issue.

Matter closed for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add up all the prices, I think you meant to type:

```
productPrice += childData.price;
```

Comment: The thing is, I tried that as well. Just edited the code. It produces correct values (namely, 69) but then the Firebase console gives me this Error: Invalid integer:. Not sure if I'm looking at the wrong issue.